# az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" >> Missing subscription,

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

When i trying to run command

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscription/<<Subscription ID>>"
```

I am getting error as

```
(MissingSubscription) The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider.

Code: MissingSubscription

Message: The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant-level resource provider.
```

I just created a new azure account where a Free Trial subscription is available with a subscription ID

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same error when I tried with scope **`"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}"`** .

**Error:**
[image]

For assigning a **`contributor`** role to Kubernetes service you need to copy the resourceId from your Kubernetes service.

***Portal->Kubernetes service->properties->Copy respurceID***

**Portal:**

[image]
**Command:**

```yaml
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes= "/subscriptions/< subscription id >/resourcegroups/< Resource group >/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/SampleAKS"
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[az ad sp | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac-examples)

**Update:**

Try passing the scopes without double quotes.

**Command:**

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes=/subscriptions/xxxxxxx
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I am trying to create a service account which is a pre-req for creating azure kubernetes cluster. I havent created any service yet.  please go thorugh this link where a instructer given steps to do so... https://github.com/in28minutes/devops-master-class/blob/master/azure-devops/readme.md

Comment: Your approach needs a kubernetes service already running, I haven't yet created that.

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan , I tried that without double quotes, still facing the same problem

Comment: What error are you getting now? please attach an error screenshot or link of the image.

Comment: Make sure you are passing valid subscription id.

Answer (score 0):

The command was not working either way, so had to register the app with contributor role manually in order to get app id and secret key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and my solution was to remove the leading slash in the `--scope` parameter as follows:

`--scopes=subscription/<<subscription ID>>`

I use it in a script to create a service identity to pull images from ACR into a Kubernetes cluster that I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes) and removed it in the script with this command:

```bash
# Determine the full registry ID
ACR_REGISTRY_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --query "id" --output tsv)
ACR_REGISTRY_ID=${ACR_REGISTRY_ID#/}
```